# Unable to run apt-get for updating packages due to interrupted dpkg

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, plymouth

I was updating the packages using `apt-get` but interrupted the whole process by doing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Now whenever I do a `$ sudo apt-get upgrade`. I get an error log like this

```
tasdik@Acer  /var/lib/dpkg/updates  sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up lightdm (1.18.3-0ubuntu1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S99runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service runlcactivator if started
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package lightdm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up docker-engine (1.12.2-0~xenial) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S99runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service runlcactivator if started
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package docker-engine (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lightdm
 docker-engine
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

Output for `$ sudo dpkg --configure -a`

```
Setting up docker-engine (1.12.2-0~xenial) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S99runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service runlcactivator if started
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package docker-engine (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up lightdm (1.18.3-0ubuntu1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S99runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service runlcactivator if started
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package lightdm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-engine
 lightdm
```

I tried removing `docker-engine` but it was showing the same errors

Any help on this is much appreciated!